# Subshells, permissions and following symlinks on OS X/Darwin: why do I get permission errors?

Tags: bash, shell, darwin

(Edit: There was a typo that caused the problem. Please see comments on existing answers)

I wanted to `stat` a file that symlinked to another file and thought that I could use subshells and readlink command substitution to do the job. For context, let me mention that this is on OS X 10.8.3 (Darwin).

But I ran into a permission denied error.

```
ujagtahb@ujags-Retina-MBP-5.local:~/Code_Pen/c_exp$(cd /usr/share/locale/; stat $(en_US/LC_COLLATE))
bash: en_US/LC_COLLATE: Permission denied
727393128 1449 crw--w---- 1 ujagtahb tty 268435496 0 "Aug 12 11:36:50 2013" "Aug 12 11:36:51 2013" "Aug 12 11:36:51 2013" "Aug 12 11:36:51 2013" 131072 0 0 (stdin)
```

I checked the output of the readlink command and sure enough, I didn't see anything wrong with it.

```
ujagtahb@ujags-Retina-MBP-5.local:~/Code_Pen/c_exp$readlink /usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_COLLATE
../la_LN.US-ASCII/LC_COLLATE
```

`stat`ing the file directly raised no error and produced the output I needed.

```
ujagtahb@ujags-Retina-MBP-5.local:~/Code_Pen/c_exp$stat /usr/share/locale/la_LN.US-ASCII/LC_COLLATE
16777218 284538 -r--r--r-- 1 root wheel 0 2086 "Aug 12 11:36:51 2013" "Jul 22 07:55:02 2012" "Jul 22 07:55:02 2012" "Jun 21 01:35:25 2012" 4096 0 0x20 /usr/share/locale/la_LN.US-ASCII/LC_COLLATE
```

What's causing the permission denied in one case but not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
(cd /usr/share/locale/; stat $(en_US/LC_COLLATE))
```

means "open a subshell, `cd` to `/usr/share/locale`, **run the command `en_US/LC_COLLATE`**, and run `stat` on the output".

But I think the command you want to run is `readlink en_US/LC_COLLATE`, not `en_US/LC_COLLATE`; so:

```
(cd /usr/share/locale/; stat $(readlink en_US/LC_COLLATE))
```

(I'm guessing this was just a typo?)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yep, it was an embarrassing typo. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(en_US/LC_COLLATE)
```

will execute string `en_US/LC_COLLATE` as command (script).

Since it does not have execute permission shell will output that error.

Probably you wanted to do it that way:

```
$(cd /usr/share/locale/; stat en_US/LC_COLLATE)
```

Comment: My bad. I should have put in a readlink command there. Sorry, I'll chalk that up to a typo.